# Handle incoming notifications: Web

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, pusher

I'm new to Pusher. I can receive the notification so far but I would like to handle custom action when the notification was arrived to the user. Where should I put `PusherPushNotifications.onNotificationReceived` in my project? I don't get the '123' in my console log. I'm using Pusher's service worker ([Pusher Service Worker](https://js.pusher.com/beams/service-worker.js)).

[Pusher Documentation](https://pusher.com/docs/beams/guides/handle-incoming-notifications/web#overriding-default-sdk-behavior)

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/beams/1.0/push-notifications-cdn.js"></script>
<script>
    PusherPushNotifications.onNotificationReceived = ({
        pushEvent,
        payload
    }) => {
        // NOTE: Overriding this method will disable the default notification
        // handling logic offered by Pusher Beams. You MUST display a notification
        // in this callback unless your site is currently in focus
        // https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user#uservisibleonly_options

        // Your custom notification handling logic here ️
        console.log('123');
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification
        pushEvent.waitUntil(
            self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, {
                body: payload.notification.body,
                icon: payload.notification.icon,
                data: payload.data,
            }),
        );
    };

    const tokenProvider = new PusherPushNotifications.TokenProvider({
        url: 'http://localhost/tutorial/auth.php',
    });

    const beamsClient = new PusherPushNotifications.Client({
        instanceId: 'instanceId',
    });

    beamsClient
        .start()
        .then(() => beamsClient.setUserId('userId', tokenProvider))
        .catch(console.error);

    // beamsClient.getUserId()
    //    .then(userId => {
    //        console.log(userId);
    //    })
    //    .catch(console.error);

    // beamsClient
    //     .stop()
    //     .catch(console.error);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `PusherPushNotifications.onNotificationReceived` function should reside in the service-worker.js file. You should then see the console log as expected, and can customise the notification and receipt behaviour.